# Music Player not pausing

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-audio

I am developing a music player using PHP/mysql and JQuery and I am having trouble "Pausing" the audio. Currently when it pauses it starts from the beginning again, Am i missing something? is there a better way to do this?

Index.php

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'config/config.php';
?>

<div class="content">
     <div class="left-sidebar">
     <table>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT mp_id, mp_name, mp_desc, mp_img, mp_media FROM media";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '
        <tr>
        <td class="image-song"><img class="song-img" src="'.$row["mp_img"].'"/>
        ' . $row["mp_name"]. '
        <audio class="media-link" src="' . $row["mp_media"]. '"> </audio> 
        <button class="left-play" type="button" onclick="playAudio(this)"><img src="images/play-button.svg"></button> 
        <button class="left-pause" onclick="pauseAudio(this)"><img src="images/pause-button.svg"></button></td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
} 
else {
    echo "No music available";
}
$conn->close();
?>
       </table>
    </div>

<div class="player-sec">
   <div class="main-player">
     
   </div>
  <div class="audio-controls">
     <span class="prev-btn"><img src="images/rewind-button.svg"></span> 
     <span class="play-btn" onClick="playAudio()"><img src="images/play-button.svg"></span> 
     <span class="next-btn"><img src="images/forward-button.svg"></span> 
   </div>
</div>

<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Javascript.js

```
function playAudio(playButton) {
    jQuery('audio').each(function() {
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime = 0;
    });

  var song = playButton.previousElementSibling;
  song.play();

   var element = document.getElementsByClassName("left-play");
   element.classList.add("active");

   var element = document.getElementsByClassName("left-pause");
   element.classList.add("pausable");
}

function pauseAudio(pauseButton) {
    jQuery('audio').each(function() {
       this.pause();
    });

    var nsong = pauseButton.getElementsByClassName("media-link");
    nsong.pause();
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it would work at all. [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a list of elements. So you shouldn't be able to call functions like pause() or access properties like classList because lists don't have such things. Are you not getting lots of console errors?

Comment: `var nsong = pauseButton.getElementsByClassName("media-link");` - your pause button does not have any descendent with the class `media-link`.

Comment: @ADyson I am just getting song.pause() isn't a function, but it does play and stop.

Comment: `var song = playButton.previousElementSibling; song.play();` - you are calling `playAudio` in two places, once without passing any parameter. So this will cause an error already.

Comment: Why is this even tagged with `PHP`? Did you verify the output of `PHP` is correct? Then please post the generated output and not the PHP

Comment: @DanBoyden `it does play and stop` well when you're playing you're accessing the element through a different technique, and your code doesn't have anything in it to cause a stop. Do you understand what I'm saying about getElementsByClassName?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I realised that as soon as you mentioned this. previousElementSibling only works because the audio is literally the previous element am i correct?

Comment: That's correct, yes.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, I will try figure out a different way of doing it.

Comment: `this.currentTime = 0;` resets the audio, so if it's paused midway and your goal is to resume, you don't want that code to run.